# Express pug not going through

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am building an express portfolio website, where I have this router on a folder called routes located in a file named index.js line 31, that is not loading at all , I am getting this error:  Cannot read property ':0' of undefined

```
`router.get('/project:id', (req, res) => {
    //console.log(data);

    const {projectData} = data; //const reference for json file data, pass in the projects property from the data.json

   const { id } = req.params; //this variable represents the id of the project

   res.render('project', {id, projectData})
});`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting this error: Cannot read property ':0' of undefined, for reference this is my repo

You’re getting this error because you’re trying to get `projectData` instead of `projects` from `data` array. Since `projectData` is not an attribute, it will be `undefined`

Also, you can avoid using `:` in the url to make it easier for the parsing,

Making those changes,

**index.js**

```
router.get('/project/:id', (req, res) => {

  const { id } = req.params;
  const {projects} = data; // use `projects` instead of `projectData`

   res.render('project', {id, projects})
});
```

**index.pug**

```
  .cell
    a(href='/project/0')
      img.thumbnail(src='static/images/project-0-main-pic.png')
      h5 A random quote generator

  .cell
    a(href='/project/1')
      img.thumbnail(src='static/images/project-1-main-pic.png')
      h5 List Pagination and Filtering

  .cell
    a(href='/project/2')
      img.thumbnail(src='static/images/project-2-main-pic.png')
      h5 Interactive Form

  .cell
    a(href='/project/3')
      img.thumbnail(src='static/images/project-3-main-pic.png')
      h5 OOP Game Show App

  .cell
    a(href='/project/4')
      img.thumbnail(src='static/images/project-4-main-pic.png')
      h5 Public API Requests
```